# fmin_slsqp function in python gives optimization successfully, but the solution is out of bounds. How to solve?

Tags: python, optimization

I use the function fmin_slsqp in python and I get as about parameters which are out of bounds. However, it says that the optimization was successfully. How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Code for the bounds:

```
a_bnds    = (0.00000001, float('inf'))  
b_bnds        = (-1,1)    
c_bnds = (0.00000001, float('inf'))
param_bnds       = [a_bnds, b_bnds, c_bnds]
```